# Viewport background images disappeared when .blend file closed and opened

Tags: 3d-view, image, blend-files

I loaded my background images to my model and placed them where I need them to be. I could not finish my project at that moment, so I saved it in hopes that I could return to it later. I opened the saved file and both the front view and side view images weren't there. However, all my settings stayed the same. My background images were still saved as datablocks in the blend file, but they wouldn't appear anywhere in the 3D view port. Why are my background images not displaying?

Comment: background images only display in orthographic view (press `NumPad 5`).

Comment: did you pack your images on the blend file?

Comment: I`ve pushed "/" button twice and images appeared. Maybe it will help somebody.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some things to check for that would impact the visibility of your background images, besides being in the proper type of view (orthographic, as distinguished from perspective view) include the following.

If you used the background images panel in the properties shelf of the 3D viewport, are the background image files still on your computer in the same place as they were when you loaded them?

If the images are in the same location, is the background images panel activated in the new instance of Blender into which you loaded your previously saved file?

Are you looking at the right view in the 3D viewport? An image is only visible if Blender thinks it is looking at the same view, so that if you used the facility to rotate the image in any direction from one of the six background image views, even if you rotate it back to the original view, Blender will still think it's in a user view, and the image will not be visible. Try pressing the numpad keys for the view for which you have background images located: for example, if you have a top view, press the  <kbd>Numpad-7</kbd> key; a left view, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Numpad-3</kbd> .

It might expedite getting an answer if you upload your blend file to [blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com), and edit your question to provide a link to the blend file.